# QSqlTableModel не вызывается rowsInserted

Tags: c++, qt

При select в QSqlTableModel не вызывается сигнал rowsInserted. И вызывается только тогда когда добавляется строка через insertRow. Но при select ведь строки в модель вставляются.

Comment: Не силён в SQL, но с чего это при select происходит insert строки?

Comment: @МишаковМаксим, не происходит insert в таблице в базе данных, а извлеченные из базы данных строки вставляются в модель и, соответственно, в представление.